# How to get the Shape Clicked without Application.Caller

Tags: winapi, vba, excel

How can I retrieve the shape that was clicked to run a macro, without using `Application.Caller`?.  Its name or the shape itself as an object.

I cant use `Application.Caller` because if the shape name is bigger than 30 characters, it retrieves only the first 30 characters.

Maybe there is an API that could retrieve the Sape object?

**Edit:**

1. I don't want to loop shapes in sheet.  Looping throug all shapes in the workbook takes too much time.
2. I can not rename the Shapes.

Thanks

Comment: Loop each shape and test if left(shp,30) = Application.caller, or hard code the shape name in the Shape Click event?

Comment: Hi ooo; Thanks for your help.  Comparing the first 30 characters might do the trick for most of the cases, but I need to be 100% sure I'm getting the right one (so I dont want to use this approach).  Unfortunatelly looping through shapes is a very slow process.

Comment: Do you really need 30 chars to identify a shape? If a lot of it is baggage then reduce the string or perform a lookup based on a shorter name.

Comment: I do need the whole name.  Cant change anything.

Comment: If you can't rename the Shape objects and you don't want to Loop through all the Shapes every time you will need to register the Shape objects with a controller and have the .OnClick name pass the Shape object's name as an argument — or use some external hook. This cannot be done simply within VBA using the system libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you rename the Shape objects in your Worksheet?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim shp As shape
Dim i As Integer

For Each shp In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes
    shp.Name = "Shape" & Format(i, "0000")
    i = i + 1
Next shp
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could manually set the .OnAction property of each shape to pass the shape name to your function:

```
Sub RenameShapes2()

    Dim shp As shape
    Dim i As Integer

    For Each shp In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes
        shp.name = "Shape" & "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_" & Format(i, "0000")
        shp.OnAction = "'userFunction """ & shp.name & """'"
        i = i + 1
    Next shp

End Sub


Sub userFunction(name As String)
    MsgBox name
End Sub
```

This allows you to have Shape names over 30 characters in length. It's kinda ugly though

Comment: If you do not use this method note that there is no guarantee that there are not multiple Shape objects with the same .Name property. If you call Shapes(<<Name>>) it will simply return you one of the Shape objects with no warning that others also matched your request

Comment: Hi JustinJDavies.  Passing the Shape name as parameter for the .OnAction Function will do the trick.  Very handy tip.  Thanks!