# One of these Excel Autoshapes is not acting like the other

Tags: excel, vba

I have the same snippet of code opening three different macros...

```
Set c = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
```

In two of them, that line captures the shape I need just fine. In the third, it throws...

> Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)':
>
> The item with the specificed name wasn't found.

Yet when I debug and highlight Application.Caller in this problem macro, I can see it knows what shape it's looking at (in this case, msoShapeSnip2SameRectangle). The ones that work are msoShapeDownArrow and msoShapeMathMultiply, if that makes any difference.

Any ideas on why it's not working in this third macro? I've tried defining it both as a Shape and Object first.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's a length limit to the value passed to `Application.Caller`

If I insert that shape type to a sheet I get a shape called "Snip Same Side Corner Rectangle 1" (length=33), but the value passed to Application.Caller is "Snip Same Side Corner Rectangl" (length=30)

Note it's not a problem with the specific shape type, just the length of the default name.  If you rename the shape to something shorter it should be fine.

EDIT: previously - [How to get the Shape Clicked without Application.Caller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582737/how-to-get-the-shape-clicked-without-application-caller)